# puppet master client certificate order deletion

Tags: certificate, puppet

i' ve a puppet master and a couple of slave server, and i' d like to change the hostname of the master system from a puppet manifest. To do this i change the neccessary files on the system (redhat, like /etc/sysconfig/network(master) , /etc/sysconfig/puppet(all) , /etc/puppet/puppet.conf(master)), and i delete the certificates from all the machines. If the manifest on the master will be executed first, everything fine, but if it' s executed on the slave first, it got stucked while it' ll have a new certificate already, but the master doesn' t know about it yet.

Is there any way to make a dependency on different machines between modules? Or any way to overwrite a certificate on the master from the slave machine (is it safe at all)?

At the moment i' ve this code (however it doesn' t have the deletion of the certificates on the slaves):

http://pastebin.com/gMeWPpcn

. Any other recommendations are also welcomed how to solve this master hostname change and certificate problem (i read about some mac address based certificates, but in this case it' s a no go).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's no way around this. After you change the hostname on the master and delete the all the client certificates, your clients will no longer be able to connect to the master.

In situations like this, it's probably best to do it manually. For example:

- Change the hostname on the master
- Delete all the client certs (on the master)
- Connect to the master from *each* of your clients and re-add them as you did initally